# multi-user web app with regular DB manipulation

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, seam

A general question, to get me started how to solve this thing:

How do I make sure, that once a DB record has been changed the other users see this in their browsers as well? Or at least upon a browser refresh?

The framework: java, jsf facelets, seam, richfaces, EJB, hibernate, maven within jboss.

A bit of description:

I have a web application which will be used by a couple of users (2-10). They manage repair and maintenance records of medical devices, i.e. there are new DB entries or updates of DB content.

I tested with a few browsers parallel, and so far, without investigation, I see changes after some time when I refresh the browser (not reliable), but certainly when I log out and in again. This is not a behaviour I want to offer. And the users wish to log in max once per day.

Thank you very much for your hints!

Comment: Do you have a `SessionFactory` per user?

Comment: No I don't. In the IdentityEJB I can find only SessionContext (but when I took over, it was a application, where no data manipulation took place. I'll look into the SessionFactory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important point before the refresh of new data is to have guaranteed your users are working in some sort of transactional context so user A will not mutate a row on your DB while user B is just about to delete this row.

Once it is ensured your users can CRUD (create, read, update, delete) shared data without negative sideeffects as a result of a missing transactional context i see two basic possibilities to update your data:

**PULL**

On refresh of a page by pressing F5 or a link like 'refresh', 'search' etc. (e.g. any request to your server) your server should always have the most updated data in its context (in case of caches and so on you want to guarantee your server context is aware of updated data). Once such a request reaches your server it should return the currently "newest" state according to its session context and/ or database (maybe there is a user in Step 4 of 5 needet to modify a record but will abort in step 5 of 5 while in this context the data may already be modified on the database inside a transaction in a way other users should see this "temporarely" modified data).

So to refresh you have your users pulling new data by using your frontend (and fire requests to you).

Note: Any Request can be used to update any session stored data of the according session. You wouldnt be the first one to have for example all of your Servlets subclassing a MainServlet that guarantees updates to the sessioncontext on any request.

**PUSH**

If your users just stare at the screen without any interaction on the UI you want to "push" updated information to them. As faar as i know using HTTP(S) you will only be able to do so using client side scripts that "simulate" a users input and fire some sort of "deliver me newest data" request.

Hope i could gave some first hints ;)

Comment: The PULL method sounds good to me. Sorry, to ask very simply: but where do I find (code) how the data is handled upon refresh? I guess I have to check the JSF out, right? I can only see, that this is used, but I didn't have to manipulate that so far. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi it depends on frameworks you may have in use but basicially your "process"-flow will in some sort be visible to the user (like Login is required to proceed to the profiles overwiev). So when your JSF get compiled by the server the resulting HTML-Output will contain links that trigger certain requests to your server. In what way the underlaying logic is implemented depends on frameworks and design decisions.

Comment: Say you use a framework like struts you would have a descriptor file struts-config.xml that brings up the mapping from a "action" url like /login.do to a Java class initializing the request handling (basicially where Servlet would kick in according to the definition of the web.xml if no Framework is in usage) as well as a following- and/or on-error- view. So in case of Struts you would have your JSF providing the .do-Link, your configuration struts-config.xml for the framework and a Entry-Point-Java class to handle the according .do-Link (action).

Comment: If you have a existing project id first determine on which technologie it runs (basicially any framework will in some sort have to be "attached" via the deployment descriptor web.xml). Then pick a action (businesscase, flow, ...) where you expect a refresh of the content will happen (for example a link/button 'search' will mostly result in displaying search-results). Once something like the search-function has been identified id try to track the behaviour until you reach the entry point to "your" classes. Somewhere from there maintenance of the session state should be handlet in some sort.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will dig into the existing code. There is no framework in use.

Comment: In that case i assume you will have a first hook by the Servlet/ Action Mappings defined in your web.xml.